# What should i do, if debug is not working correctly (Eclipse IDE, Android SDK)?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I don't know if this question is suitable for this site or not, but I think this place is better for this kind of question than stackoverflow.

I'm developing an Android application using Eclipse. I always `debug` and `log` when I encounter a complex problem/bug when developing apps.

However, this is the first time I encountered a situation where `debug` and `log` seem not working correctly. This is what happened:

1. When I run my apps (using log) : The `getView` method  in my adapter is **not** called, i know this by using log.
2. When I debug it step by step : The `getView` method  in my adapter is called, however it gives me the `NPE` (Null Pointer Exception).
3. When I debug it, but not step by step : Same like when i run my apps, the program never entered the `getView` method.

**Note :** The 3rd means that I set some breakpoints, then I debug what I need to debug (not step by step), then I skip to the next breakpoint, while the 2nd means I debug the apps step by step, not skipping anything.

I have tried to solve this bug for more than 20 hours, but I still can't get things working correctly.

**Have you encountered the same problem like mine, while running and debugging a program, or even different method of debugging give you a different result?**

**What should I do now?**

Comment: Please give more details or samples of what happens when running the apps in different modes.

Comment: Create a [simple, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you working with threads ? if yes please check code your for synchronization blocks. These kind of problems happens when you miss some code blocks for synchronization. Always behavior will be strange.